# RecyclerView image wrong position

Tags: android

H1, i have RecyclerView adapter, which dynamically create ImageView and load image by url:

```
ImageView image;

if (list.size() > 0) {
    if (list.size() > 2) {
        holder.attachments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.attachments_multi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.attachments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.attachments_multi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++) {
        image = createImage();
        imageLoader.cancelDisplayTask(image);
        if (i < 2) {
            holder.attachments.addView(image);
        } else {
            holder.attachments_multi.addView(image);
        }
        loadImage(imageLoader, image, apiSettings.server_images + list.get(i), options);
    }
} else {
    holder.attachments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.attachments_multi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Create image simple:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);
...
return image
```

holder.attachments - LinearLayout for first 2 images

holder.attachments_multi - LinearLayout for other images;

And items ImageView have wrong positions when scroll. What problem?

Comment: You can use Picasso library for loading images. You will not get this issue then. https://github.com/square/picasso